# Looping through numbered html tag id's

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, for-loop

I'm having an issue where I am not able to loop through the id's of multiple canvas tags which I have created to edit various pixel data. All the canvases have id's ranging from 0 - n. But when the id's are created, the numbers are turned into strings.

So, if I create a loop which iterates through the numbers which correspond to the id's of the tags, how do I make it so the .getElementById(); method will recognize the number value as a string value? (this might be a little unclear but the code should clear things up)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
var useGetImageData = function(i){

    var canvas=document.getElementById(i);
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
   }
}
```

the canvas id's are; "0", "1", "2"

Comment: You could use `document.getElementById(''+i);`

Comment: You can also do that: 
`var i = 42;  i.toString(); // "42"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You also weren't calling the function (which is bad to create inside a loop anyhow).

```
var useGetImageData = function(i){

    var canvas=document.getElementById(i);
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // useGetImageData(''+i);
    // As @Andrew points out, it gets interpreted as a string.
    userGetImageData(i);
}
```

Comment: No need to use `''+i` to convert the number to a string.

Comment: ok but I get a type error which states that I cannot .getContext of null. Isn't that because var canvas is not calling the correct element?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more? Maybe a piece of the output HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything, `getElementById` already knows that element ids are always strings. The code you posted just works.

http://jsfiddle.net/FXS8u/